# Mysql EF Core char column with null value throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: mysql, ef-core-3.1

I had a requirement to read some data from a MySql server for an API solution.
The database was scaffolded and we came across a problem where GUIDs are stored in a 'char(36) DEFAULT NULL'
when trying to read entities with that column and the database value is null the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query: Error: An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'DbContext'.
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required. (Parameter 'count')
   at System.Text.EncodingNLS.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Non-negative number required. (Parameter 'count')
   at System.Text.EncodingNLS.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadColumnValue(Int32 index, MySqlField field, IMySqlValue valObject)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.ReadColumnData(Boolean outputParms)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.NextRow(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Read()
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
```

**Scaffolded model:**

```
    public class XTable
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProblemColumn { get; set; }
    }

    modelBuilder.Entity<XTable>(entity =>
    {
         entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PRIMARY");
         entity.ToTable("XTable");
         entity.Property(e => e.ProblemColumn)
               .HasColumnName("problemColumn")
               .HasMaxLength(36)
               .IsFixedLength();
    }

**Context DBSet**
public virtual DbSet<XTable> XTables{ get; set; }

**Example of use case**
var result = dbContext.XTables.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);
```

**Environment:**
.Net Standard 2.0 consumed by 3.1 asp netcore

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.9
MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.22

Did update dependencies to latest stables as shown above.

As mentioned narrowed it to only when the row column value is null, I tried various variations of the model removing "HasMaxLength", "IsFixedLength" that made no difference.

If the row value in the database is blank or has a guid in it reads fine.

Just wondering if anyone aware of MySQL and ef core with char columns issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug of MySql.Data version 8.0.22. I have the same issue and waiting for the next release.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101252